# How to add a sorted array of elements to a binary search tree (in c#)

Tags: c#, binary-tree

So I am implementing a BST, and right now I am trying to add the items from a sorted array.

I have a recursive function Dup:

```
private BNode Dup(T[] arr, int start, int end) {

    if (start > end) return null;

    BNode sub_root = new BNode(arr[(int)Math.Ceiling((double)((start + end) / 2))]);
    sub_root.Left = Dup(arr, start, (start + end) / 2 - 1);
    sub_root.Right = Dup(arr, (start + end) / 2 + 1, end);
    return sub_root;

}
```

But if I pass it in an array that looks like [1,1], it adds the 1 at position 0 of the array, and then doesnt add the 1 at position 0 in the left subtree, (because when we make the recursive call, start = 0, end = -1), and then puts the other 1 into the right subtree (which is wrong!).

This is the only case I can see that doesn't work..

Any ideas how to fix it? (I think it is most likely a math error)

thanks!

Comment: Isn't it a pre-condition that `arr` is sorted?  `[1, 0]` isn't.

Comment: right. it isnt...i will update my above example. I had 1,0 to make it more clear (than 1,1)...

Comment: Is the interval right inclusive or exclusive? Like [start, end] or [start, end) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not reuse the same split index? Something like:

```
int splitIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(start + end) / 2);
BNode sub_root = new BNode(arr[splitIndex]);
sub_root.Left = Dup(arr, start, splitIndex  - 1);
sub_root.Right = Dup(arr, splitIndex + 1, end);
return sub_root;
```

Comment: I was just in the process of typing this when I saw you posted this!! haha. it works great, thanks!

Comment: And then you can use `Assert(splitIndex >= start)` etc to make your proc self-documenting and self-checking.

Comment: ok..it is actually not quit working right....if I add 1 1 1 1 1 1 etc, after I call this dup function, there are 1's on right subtree's of other 1's :( ...I have if(start > end) return null...not >=, if I add the equals, it skips a lot of nodes

Comment: after closer inspection, I dont think it will work if the tree allows dupicate values